# VirtualBox E_FAIL error when adding host-only network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, drivers, network-adapter, host-only

When I tried to add a host-only network to VirtualBox, it gave me this error:

```
Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (76) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Utf8Str,class com::Utf8Str,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0046).
Please contact the product vendor!.

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
```

I just upgraded VirtualBox (6.1.38) and Windows 11 (22H2). I also reset my network adapters because of an unrelated network issue. Now, my host-only adapter is gone, and I can't add another one. Before the reset and upgrade, my VMs worked normally. I tried the following:

- Re-installing VBox 6.1.36
- Deleting the host-only driver (that resulted in another error)
- Turning off the Virtual Machine Platform and Hypervisor in Windows Features (other users said those interfered with VBox)

Before I deleted the driver, there was a "Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" in the Device Manager, like this:
[VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr0RB.png)

This happens **in the VBox settings**, not in any particular VM. How can I get my host-only adapter back?

Host OS: Windows 11 22H2

Model: HP Laptop 15t-dy200

Network: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (but I don't think that's causing the problem)

Comment: Try in VirtualBox to right-click the VM and select "Discard Saved State". Check if you have a `.vbox` file for the VM, or it was renamed to `.vbox-prev` and rename back to `.vbox`. Better take a backup copy of the VM before starting.